# How to use Trend and If together in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, trend

I am trying to calculate the slope of a curve which is approximately linear using the TREND function. However, I would only like to calculate the slope up to a certain point specified by the value in a particular cell.

I have attached a picture of my data. I would like to find the slope of the A and P columns, where Ro is the x. I only want to find the slope for values where Ro<=$B$2.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try the OFFSET function: this allows you to specify a Range by giving a Cell, row and column offset, row and column count. If you add the row count based on the limit until which you want to take the data into account.

Comment: @z32a7ul will that let me specify a range based off the value in E2 in my data?

Comment: I can't see which one is E2, the header is missing.

Comment: Sorry I'll fix it

Comment: @z32a7ul, ok I put a better image now. Also, I meant to say B2 not E2.

Comment: I would try something like: =TREND( OFFSET( A6, 0, 0, MATCH( E2, A6:A26, 1), 1 ), ... ). I assumed here that X values are in column A, and you have to add the why values similarly.

Comment: @z32a7ul, awesome after a few changes it worked perfectly.

Comment: @z32a7ul Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I proposed in the comments:

I would try something like:

```
=TREND( OFFSET( A6, 0, 0, MATCH( E2, A6:A26, 1), 1 ), ... ).
```

I assumed here that X values are in column A, and you have to add the why values similarly.